# TeXStudio and SVN + Linux

Tags: texstudio, linux, subversion

I cannot in any way understand how the heck I'm supposed to ->connect<- to a SVN server through TeXStudio! I've googled guides for two hours and can't find a simple answer to how to connect to an external SVN server.

I want to connect to a directory on a webserver, download a working directory and start working with TeXStudio. Is there any simple guide on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! But... http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION08?

Comment: There must be some basic concept I don't get, because I've read that and done what it says. But how does it help me to connect?

Comment: @Cottus: Please see http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts to merge the two accounts you created. Then you can comment and edit your old posts.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot checkout a repository via TeXstudio. Just use the normal tools for this (either `svn checkout` on the commmand line or the GUI of your choice). Once you have a working copy, TeXstudio can operate on it.

Answer (score 0):

One bit that can cause problems is overlooking the following line in the TeXstudio manual info about configuring SVN support (now at https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/master/utilities/manual/usermanual_en.html#SECTION08):

> The complete path to the command "svn" and "svnadmin" need to be
> adjusted in the aprioriate [sic] field of the Commands page in the
> options.

Entries for SVN and SVNADMIN in the "Configure TeXstudio" dialog are `svn` and `svnadmin` by default, but this is apparently insufficient even if those commands are in a directory on your PATH and thus should be accessible anywhere. It's instead necessary to specify the full path to these commands; for example, if they're in `/usr/bin` then it's necessary to specify `/usr/bin/svn` and `/usr/bin/svnadmin` in the "Configure TeXstudio" dialog.